# Double Interpolation in Angular component.html

Tags: angular, google-cloud-firestore

In my Cloud Firestore document `messages`, I have the field `day = "monday"`, and I also have the fields `monday = "foo"`, `tuesday = "bar"`,  `wednesday = "taco"`, and `thursday = "beer"`.

I would like to write something like

```
<div *ngIf="message | async as message; else loading">
{{ message.{{message.day}} }}
```

in order to get the result of `foo`.

Is there any way to do this sort of double-interpolation?
Thank you.

Comment: Just like you would do it in JavaScript: {{ message[message.day] }}

Comment: @JBNizet I tried that, but received an error ```Parser Error: Unexpected token [, expected identifier or keyword at column 8 in [ {{ message.[message.day] }} ]```

Comment: My eyes skipped. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```html
<div *ngIf="message | async as message; else loading">
{{ message[message.day] }}
```